# Multiple(more than 2) Drop-down list menu using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

I want to make 5 drop down menu where 5th depends on 4th,4th on 3rd........2nd on 1st,like this. I have made two drop down list using php and an ajax call and a line code of javascript. Now I want to extend it to 5 menus. How do I do that.Does anyone have any link where there is tutorial for more than 2 drop down dependent menu.

Comment: Or not to extend but from scratch, data is retrieved from the 5 tables of mysql.

Comment: Can you share some example code and/or explain what you currently have working? That would be beneficial in helping you get the functionality you're looking for.